# Image are not showing in table View

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I have a JSON link and I am using Alamofire for parsing data to my table view. I have got Text from Json but images are not showing.

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var newsArray = [AnyObject]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

**Here JSON is Called**

```
Alamofire.request("http://iccukapp.org/Api_json_format").responseJSON { response in
         let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

            if let innerDict = dict["result"]{
                self.newsArray = innerDict as! [AnyObject]
                self.tableView.reloadData()



            }
        }


    }

}
```

**Here data are load into table view**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return newsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let title = newsArray[indexPath.row]["title"]
    cell.newsLabel.text = title as? String
```

this url is my image url but if i look at my JSON there is no url before the image name. here is my json link http://iccukapp.org/Api_json_format . 
i have image asset link. link is here http://iccukapp.org/assets/admin/images/[enter link description here](http://iccukapp.org/assets/admin/images/)

Is there any way add external link to my url?

```
    let url = NSURL(string: self.newsArray[indexPath.row]["post_iamge"]! as! String)

    cell.imageVieww.af_setImage(withURL: url! as URL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "loadig.gif"), filter: nil, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: nil)


    return cell
}
```

}

Advanced thank's.

Comment: "self.newsArray" have image name not a image url.plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append your server url with your image string .

```
let fullImageUrl = "your serverurl" + (self.newsArray[indexPath.row]["post_iamge"]! as! String)
 let url = URL(string: fullImageUrl) as URL
 cell.imageVieww.af_setImage(withURL: url!, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "loadig.gif"), filter: nil, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to append the image name to the image asset link and then use that url to show the image. Try this

```
let imageUrl = "http://iccukapp.org/assets/admin/images/" + (self.newsArray[indexPath.row]["post_iamge"]! as! String)
let url = NSURL(string:imageUrl)
cell.imageVieww.af_setImage(withURL: url! as URL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "loadig.gif"), filter: nil, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: nil)
```